# Expect() assertion for modal pop up in lwc test

Tags: lightning, unit-test, lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have an lwc component which is used for file uploading purposes.
Below is the code related to modal pop up from html mark up of the component

```
<template if:true={isModalOpen}>
            <c-custom-component-modal
                id="popup"
                content-docs={uploadedFileIds}
                onclose={closeModal}
                ondelete={deleteFileById}>
            </c-custom-component-modal>
        </template>
```

Can anyone please let me know the expect() assertion of the above snippet so that I can validate this in LWC jest test class.

Thanks!